# Spring or Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

As part of a new web application project, I'm planning to learn Spring. I started to read through the Spring framework reference. While I was googling, I came across Spring boot. What I understood is that spring boot helps to build application much faster than spring by reducing configuration. Now I'm little confused whether should I continue learning spring or jump to spring boot. My intention is to understand how spring works as a framework rather than a few features. So please let me know, as a beginner what should I do? First, learn Spring and then spring boot or vice-versa.

**Update**

Ok, I know it's a while since I asked this question. I kind of have an answer (personal one)

I started with Spring Boot and so far built one Spring Boot REST application. Yes, as others said, Spring Boot, helps you to get started quickly and being new to some language/technology, I would love to see a working module ASAP. So Spring boot helps you with that. 
Later depending on your interest, you can start exploring in-depth how Spring boot does that magic.

So, in summary, go with Spring Boot and then deep dive to understand the underlying concept. Again this is my opinion.

Thanks, everyone for your inputs/suggestions.

Comment: Your question will likely get closed but I'll try to help. Spring Boot is to Spring what a baked caked is to the ingredients used to make it. Learning Spring Boot just means learning how to take advantage of all of the "automagically" configured goodness and learning how to make your work as a developer much less tedious. You need to learn Spring in order to have any concept of what Spring Boot is really doing for you.

Comment: @ zero01alpha, thanks for the comment. I will learn concepts of Spring first and then use Spring Boot to take its advantage.

Comment: I was in a similar situation some 2 years ago, and decided to go with learning plain Spring first and then move on to Spring Boot. In my opinion it was the right decision because you will be able to grasp the concepts of spring boot faster once u start learning it, and it you will be able to track down and understand issues much better because under the hood its still just Spring.

Comment: Indeed @zero01alpha, question is too opinionated and broad. That's why I've voted to close it as such.

Comment: When you learn driving, do you learn about the internals of the car first?Depends. And voted to close.

Comment: The question will get closed, but from my own experience I wished that I had learned Spring before starting with Spring Boot. Otherwise, Spring Boot feels like magic. It gets better if you understand more about Spring itself.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar As a regular user of the car, no. But for a driver that wishes to diagnose his own problems and understand how his car is actually going down the road i'd say its important.

Comment: @zero01alpha I concur, and hence said before, depends.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Here here

Answer (score 7):

If you want to develop web applications especially micro-services, I will recommend that you should learn Spring Boot first.

- The first reason is that there are many resources and examples on
  web, so you can easily find what you need.
- The second reason is that Spring Framework (including Spring Boot) is
  suitable for PaaS environment especially Pivotal. Therefore you can
  rapidly deploy your applications without too much effort.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, learn how Spring applications work.

Spring applications are based on the Object Relation Model. You need to understand the annotations and why we use them. Then you have to learn how Spring MVC works. Up to here, both Spring and Spring Boot are similar. Basically, Spring Boot is made so that a Spring-based application can be made very easily.  Spring Boot is very good framework for the Web and other.

After learning the above things, then you can jump easily onto Spring Boot. However, if you jump directly to Spring Boot you will see there are many such things which are not described in the Spring Boot tutorials, since many of them expect that you have some prior knowledge of Spring.